# Вывод в строку с чисткой консоли, с++

Tags: c++, консоль

Задание:
Нужно сделать перевод °C в °F при этом вывод должен выглядеть:

```
Введите градусы цельсия:
43°C = 200°F 
20°C = 130°F
56°C = 280°F
```

Градусы Цельсия вводятся с клавиатуры, градусы Фаренгейта считаются в программе.
Нужно реализовать ИМЕННО вывод, все остальное я знаю.

Comment: проблема в том, что нужно вывести символ градуса?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Короче решил так:
Создал массив в который вносил по очереди цельсии и фаренгейты, и зациклил вывод:

```
int Mass[100];
            next:
            cout << "Введите температуру в фаренгейтах:\n";
            if (i > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (Mass[j] != 0)
                    {
                        int d = Mass[j];
                        j++;
                        if (d > 0)
                        cout.setf(ios::showpos);
                        cout << d << "°F" << " = " << Mass[j] << "°C\n";
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            cin >> farh;
            cel = (farh - 32) * 5 / 9;
            Mass[i] = farh;
            i++;
            Mass[i] = cel;
            system("cls");
            if (i >= 100) {
                i = 0;
            }
            goto next;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << setw(2) << t_c << "°C = " << setw(3) << t_f << "°F\n";
```

Если больше привлекает C -

```
printf("%2d°C = %3d°F\n",t_c,t_f);
```

Вас это интересовало?

О "чистке консоли" - если вы хотите убрать все с консоли, чтоб там было совсем пусто, а потом выводить текст - то стандартом это не предусмотрено, это уже нужны консольные функции. Или прогон большого количества символов перевода на новую строку :)

Или вам нужно что-то иное?

Comment: Самое первое сработало бы, но цельсии я ввожу вручную и считаю фаренгейты и вот нужен вывод как вверху

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите **дописывать** ко вводу пользователя? Стандартно - не вижу возможности: пользователь должен подтвердить ввод нажатием Enter. Нужно использовать консольные функции - типа `getch()`, перехватывать каждое нажатие клавиши, собирать число самому, по нажатии Enter выполнить вычисления и вывести результат...

Comment: Гугл подсказывает, что есть порт [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) в винду (вопрос  так выглядит). Значит можно.

Comment: @avp Конечно, можно. Но **НЕ СТАНДАРТНЫМИ СРЕДСТВАМИ ЯЗЫКА**. А с использованием API операционной системы - запросто. Давненько не заглядывал в `<conio.h>`, но во времена оны там точно была функция типа `clrscr()`. В конце-концов, в Windows не зря целый набор Console-функций имеется...